# How to switch URxvt.transparent setting on the fly?

Tags: terminal, rxvt

I would like to set a key binding in my xressources to switch the transparency setting in a terminal (without having to start another one to see changes).

I didn't find a `bindsym` option that allows changing xressources settings, nor did I find an escape sequence that does what I'm looking for, but I may be missing something.